C++17 constexpr function to convert an array to a different sized array
I'm asking if it's possible to convert a function like the following:
string escape(const string& s)
{
    string r = "";
    for(char c:s)
    {
        if(c=='"') 
        {
            r+='\\'; r+=c;
        }
        else r+=c;
    }
    return r;
}

into something like:
constexpr const char* escape(const char* s) { ??? }

This is an example to illustrate a general constexpr array[N]->array[M] approach where M depends on the contents of array[N]. The solution may benefit a few contexts. I'm compiling to a platform where every bit of RAM matters and I'm trying to push as much data as possible to a read-only section while also preserving code clarity (and make it from C++ syntax). I heard it may be possible with C++20 but I don't consider switching to a whole new standard only to get this particular issue fixed, so I'm wondering if we can achieve with what we already have.
The solution I tried relies on upper bounds imposed on the output. If the input has N characters, the output would have be most 2*N size (worst case when for full-quotes string ""..."->\"\"...\"). The code looks roughly like this:
template<int N>
struct static_str { char data[N]; };

template<int N>
constexpr static_str<2*N> escape(static_str<N> s)
{
    static_str<2*N> r;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(s.data[i]=='"') { r.data[k++]='\\'; }
        r.data[k++] = s.data[i];
    }
    return r;
}

However, it is clear that this method wastes memory considering the average length of output. I had some ideas to solve this, but they failed due to some limitations or missing puzzle pieces:

You can precompute the length of the output (expected_len(s) := strlen(s)+<n.o. quotes>), but then you're not allowed to create a variable of type static_str<expected_len(s)> - "expected_len(s) is not a constant".

Supposing I use the above escape(s) function to obtain the 2*N sized output, I thought I could trim the array to keep its first elements until it matches expected_len(s). But I have no idea how to do that without conflicting with template mechanics.

What if the output size is not that easily predictable?



So basically what you want is to replace double-quotes (") with backslash-escaped ones (\") in compile-time strings?

Your function has to return a single type for a fixed set of template parameters. It is impossible to make f(static_str<2>) return static_str<3> for one input and static_str<4> for another, whatever f is.

Are you set on C++17 or is C++20 a possibility (with std::string being mostly constexpr in this version)?

With C++20 you can pass the function argument as template argument instead, which lifts the whole value of the argument into the type level and then you can decide on the return type based on the value, rather than just the type, of the argument.

If you're planning to stay on C++17, are macros an option?

This would take some template-trickery, but I wonder: if you made a compile-time string an std::array, e.g. std::array<char, std::size("abcd")>{"abcd"}; then I guess you could convert that to tuple and back. Granted, tuple insertion in the middle would took some template programming and I'm not sure if it's worth it. I can try later as an exercise ;-)

@alagner: having a char_sequence is directly possible with gcc extension (or with some code with MACRO).

A possibility is to first compute as constexpr the size of the target array.
If we have that, we can allocate a std::array of the required size and initialize it according to the requirement. However, the required size can't be provided as parameter of a function since it wouldn't be usable as constexpr, so we can provide it as non-type template argument.
In order to keep the API simple (ie. a single call to escape with the input string), we have to (unfortunately) rely on the preprocessor.
Here is the code:
#include <array>

// we get the size and the occurrences number in the provided string
constexpr auto info (const char* str, char c)
{
    int size=0;
    int found=0;
    while (*str)
    {
        if(*str==c) { found++; }
        str++;
        size++;
    }
    return std::make_pair(size,found);
}

// we provide the size and occurs number as non-type template parameters
template<int size, int occurs>
constexpr auto escape_impl (const char* s, char c)
{
    // we can allocate the result array with the required size
    std::array<char,size+occurs> r {};

    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==c) { r[k++]='\\'; }
        r[k++] = s[i];
    }

    return r;
}

// We can't provide size and occurs number as function parameters 
// because they would not be constexpr. So we have to provide them
// as non-type template arguments.
#define escape(s,c) escape_impl<info(s,c).first, info(s,c).second> (s,c) 

static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b').size() == 6);
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [0] == 'a' );
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [1] == '\\');
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [2] == 'b' );
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [3] == 'a' );
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [4] == '\\');
static_assert (escape ("abab", 'b') [5] == 'b' );

int main() 
{
}

Demo

Issue is that parameter are not constexpr, so you have to use some template argument to pass them:
With gcc extension, you might simply have:
// Sequence of char
template <char... Cs> struct char_sequence{};

template <typename CHAR, CHAR... cs>
constexpr auto operator ""_c() { return char_sequence<cs...>{}; }

else you might use my MACRO way
then it becomes relatively easy to implement:
template <char... Cs>
constexpr auto escape_to_array(char_sequence<Cs...>)
{
    constexpr auto size = (0 + ... + (Cs == '"' ? 2 : 1));
    std::array<char, size> a{};
    int i = 0;
    for (auto c : {Cs...}) {
        if (c == '"') a[i++] = '\\';
        a[i++] = c;
    }
    return a;
}

template <std::size_t... Is, char... Cs>
constexpr auto escape_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>, char_sequence<Cs...> cseq)
{
    constexpr auto a = escape_to_array(cseq);
    return char_sequence<a[Is]...>{};
}

template <char... Cs>
constexpr auto escape(char_sequence<Cs...> cseq)
{
    constexpr auto a = escape_to_array(cseq);
    return escape_helper(std::make_index_sequence<a.size()>(), cseq);
}

or C++20 version
template <char... Cs>
constexpr auto escape(char_sequence<Cs...>)
{
    constexpr std::array a = [](){
        constexpr auto size = (0 + ... + (Cs == '"' ? 2 : 1));
        std::array<char, size> a{};
        int i = 0;
        for (auto c : {Cs...}) {
           if (c == '"') a[i++] = '\\';
           a[i++] = c;
        }
        return a;
    }();
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return char_sequence<a[Is]...>{};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<a.size()>());
}

Demo

To achieve a constexpr version of your escape function that works with const char* and avoids wasting memory, you can use a combination of template metaprogramming and constexpr functions. The key is to precompute the length of the output string at compile time and then use that length to create a properly sized array.
Here’s a solution that demonstrates this approach:
Precompute the length of the escaped string.
Create a constexpr function to perform the escaping.
Step 1: Precompute the Length
First, you need a constexpr function to calculate the length of the escaped string:
constexpr std::size_t escaped_length(const char* s) {
    std::size_t length = 0;
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '"') {
            length += 2; // One for the quote and one for the backslash
        } else {
            length += 1;
        }
        ++s;
    }
    return length;
}

Step 2: Perform the Escaping
Next, we create a constexpr function to perform the escaping:
template<std::size_t N>
struct static_str {
    char data[N + 1] = {}; // +1 for the null terminator
};

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr static_str<N> escape(const char (&s)[N]) {
    constexpr std::size_t new_length = escaped_length(s);
    static_str<new_length> result = {};
    std::size_t k = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) { // N-1 to exclude the null 
        terminator
        if (s[i] == '"') {
            result.data[k++] = '\\';
            result.data[k++] = '"';
        } else {
            result.data[k++] = s[i];
        }
    }
    result.data[k] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
    return result;
}


parameter are not constexpr, so new_length cannot be neither :/ Demo

escaped_length(s) can not be evaluated in constexpr context. Try to use the template in a static_cast expression and you will realize that.
